# When using an Ansible playbook, how do you store and use a password containing quotes or other metacharacters without them being interpereted?

Tags: python, ansible, password, yaml, jinja2

My company uses Ansible (which I am a novice at) and we have a playbook and a related role for joining new Linux machines to AD.  Our admin accounts have their passwords rolled three times a day, and we can't set them ourselves.  The Ansible playbook works so long as there is *not* a `'` (single quote) in the password.  There may be other characters that cause it to break, but I know that `'` does it for sure.

Here are the relevant bits of the scripts:

```
cat setup-ad.yml

---
- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"

  vars_prompt:
  - name: "username"
    prompt: "Enter admin account"
    private: no

  - name: "password"
    prompt: "Enter Password"
    unsafe: yes
    private: yes

  vars:
    domain: "{{ 'mycompany.com' }}"
    passwd: "{{ password | regex_escape() }}"

  roles:
  - join-ad
```

```
grep -B2 -A3 'passwd' ./roles/join-ad/tasks/main.yml

  - name: join to active directory
    command: net ads join MYCOMPANY.COM -U {{ username }}@MYCOMPANY.COM%'{{ passwd }}' createcomputer=Restricted/Servers/Unix --request-timeout=120 --no-dns-updates
    no_log: false
    when: ansible_distribution_major_version >= 6

  - name: join to active directory
    command: net ads join MYCOMPANY.COM -U {{ username }}@MYCOMPANY.COM%'{{ passwd }}' createcomputer=Restricted/Servers/Unix --request-timeout=120
    no_log: false
    when: ansible_distribution_major_version <= 5
```

The error we get is:

```
TASK [join-ad : join to active directory] ************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ValueError: No closing quotation
fatal: [newserver.mycompany.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to newserver.mycompany.com closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1590785720.2-224244797633747/AnsiballZ_command.py\", line 102, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1590785720.2-224244797633747/AnsiballZ_command.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1590785720.2-224244797633747/AnsiballZ_command.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\r\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.commands.command', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 176, in run_module\r\n    fname, loader, pkg_name)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 82, in _run_module_code\r\n    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 72, in _run_code\r\n    exec code in run_globals\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_command_payload_4D4oFT/ansible_command_payload.zip/ansible/modules/commands/command.py\", line 344, in <module>\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_command_payload_4D4oFT/ansible_command_payload.zip/ansible/modules/commands/command.py\", line 263, in main\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/shlex.py\", line 279, in split\r\n    return list(lex)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/shlex.py\", line 269, in next\r\n    token = self.get_token()\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/shlex.py\", line 96, in get_token\r\n    raw = self.read_token()\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/shlex.py\", line 172, in read_token\r\n    raise ValueError, \"No closing quotation\"\r\nValueError: No closing quotation\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
newserver.mycompany.com : ok=9    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Okay, so the issue is that at some point the `'` is being interpreted as the beginning of a quoted series of characters, rather than as simply part of the password.  My problem is I don't know how to get Ansible? Python? YAML? Jinja? to treat the string of characters the user inputs as nothing more than a string of characters.  Is "string literal" the correct term here?

If I ssh to the target server and run the `net ads join` command manually, and let it prompt for my password, it will work even with a `'` in it, so at the very least I know it's not the Samba command that's the issue.

The things I've tried (which haven't helped) are:

- Add 'hard quotes' around `{{ passwd }}`
- Add `unsafe: yes` to the password definition
- Add `passwd: "{{ password | regex_escape() }}"` to escape metacharacters
- Lots of internet searching on Stack and Google

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Vladimir Botka thank you!  Replacing `passwd: "{{ password | regex_escape() }}"` with `passwd: "{{ password | quote }}"`, and surrounding the whole command line with `"`'s  while removing the interior `'`'s like you suggested solved it for me!  If you add your suggestions as an answer I will mark it as the chosen solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  might be what you're looking for

```yaml
- command: "net ads join MYCOMPANY.COM
            -U {{ username }}@MYCOMPANY.COM%{{ passwd|quote }}
            createcomputer=Restricted/Servers/Unix --request-timeout=120"
```

See [YAML gotcha](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#hey-wait-a-yaml-gotcha) and [String filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#string-filters).